# Combine query and use 1 datareader

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I want to receive two values from a datareader. But I don't know how to put this into one query. And how can I receive it by using just one sqldatareader?

```
 string query = "select date from ars.kmstand where ritnr=(select max(ritnr) from ars.kmstand)";
        string query2 = "select nr from ars.kmstand where ritnr=(select max(ritnr) from ars.kmstand)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
        SqlDataReader rt = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (rt.Read())
        {
            ritnr = rt.GetInt32(0);
        }
        rt.Close();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            value = rd.GetSqlDateTime(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine queries and pass column index to GetXXX methods of IDataReader get value of each column from the result set.

```
string query = "select nhr, date from ars.kmstand where ritnr=(select max(ritnr) from ars.kmstand)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
SqlDataReader rt = com.ExecuteReader();
while (rt.Read())  {
    int nhr = rt.GetInt32(0);
    SqlDateTime date = rt.GetSqlDateTime(1);
}
rt.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot shorter and better. Really helpful !

Answer (score 0):

The [`NextResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult.aspx) method on `DbDataReader` and its derived types (including `SqldataReader`) will move from one data set to the next.

Hence:

```
// ...
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read()) {
  // Read rows from the first dataset
}

if (rdr.NextResult()) {
  // There is a second dataset
  while (rdr.Read()) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

In the command, just have multiple operations that each return rows (and this could be within a stored procedure you execute).